# Why is it that the non pivot columns of a matrix allow you to freely pick the variable which scales that column.

Tags: linear-algebra

I was watching this lecture on linear algebra, how to a linear system of equations where AX=0, where A is some matrix multiplying the vector X. In the lecture it was stated that if upon doing row eliminations a non pivot column is found, we can freely assign any variable for it. Why is this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of the definition of [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form).

By definition, each nonzero row of an augmented matrix in reduced row echelon form corresponds to an equation where exactly one of the variables in a pivot column has coefficient equal to one. This means that the equations defined by a reduced row echelon form system allow one to solve for each "pivot" variable in terms of the "nonpivot" variables.

For example, consider the reduced row echelon form system
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
1 & 0 & -5 & 0 & -2 & 6 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 11 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -16 & -9
\end{array}\right]
$$
The "pivot" variables are $\{x_1, x_2, x_4\}$ and the "nonpivot" variables are $\{x_3, x_5\}$. The first row is the equation
$$
x_1-5\,x_3-2\,x_5=6
$$
which allows us to solve for $x_1$ in terms of $\{x_3, x_5\}$ giving $x_1=6+5\,x_3+2\,x_5$.

The second two equations give $x_2=7-2\,x_3-11\,x_5$ and $x_4=-9+16\,x_5$.

Putting these relations together gives the general solution to the system as
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{5}
\end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{r}
5 \, x_{3} + 2 \, x_{5} + 6 \\
-2 \, x_{3} - 11 \, x_{5} + 7 \\
x_{3} \\
16 \, x_{5} - 9 \\
x_{5}
\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{r}
6 \\
7 \\
0 \\
-9 \\
0
\end{array}\right]+x_3\left[\begin{array}{r}
5 \\
-2 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]+x_5\left[\begin{array}{r}
2 \\
-11 \\
0 \\
16 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
So, we may "freely" choose values of $x_3$ and $x_5$. Once these values are set, our formula automatically determines values of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_4$.